# Float Creates Overlapping Divs

Tags: html, css

I have two divs (one inside of the other) and am running into a bit of a problem when I float the one inside to "left".  The problem is that the outer div doesn't expand its height to fit the text inside of the inner div.  Since this is probably pretty confusing, I'll try to explain it with some code.

HTML:

```html
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        Inner Div:
        <div id="div2">Testing long content.</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
#div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
}
```

I rather hope that when tested this actually shows my problem as I have not had a chance to test this.  My real code has more properties which I will pose these if needed.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to use the clear-fix. Insert the following after your floated div, and within the containing div.

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

And add the following style:

```
.clear { clear:both; }
```

Example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="floatedDiv">Hello World</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not a fix. It is just clear. You just need to clear the floating :)

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to add additional markup to your html or add a width to your outer div, you can use:

```
#div1 {
    overflow:hidden;   /* clears float for most browsers */
    zoom:1;            /* clears float for IE6           */
    }
```

Comment: Nope. To clear floats for IE6 you need to invoke hasLayout.  That is done by giving the element a position, float, display, width, height, or zoom. Giving width or height is the most common way to invoke hasLayout but sometimes you don't want to specify a dimension and zoom is the most transparent.  See hasLayout.net for more information.

Comment: Ah - I add display: block to generally everything that contains floated elements.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe handy to note that there is also the well know clearfix code from [positioniseverything](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) that is written specifically for this problem and is probably most robust and easiest to apply in any situation. The CSS looks as follows:

```
<style>
div.clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden; }
div.clearfix { display: inline-block; margin: 0 0 8px 0; }
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html div.clearfix { height: 1%; }
div.clearfix { display: block; }
/* End hide from IE-mac */
</style>
```

In order to use it in your situation you would do the following:

```
<body>
<div id="div1" class="clearfix" >Inner Div:
<div id="div2">Testing long content.</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: the height: 1% solved my whole issue. Not sure why though. Could you explain what it does in the context of a series of floating elements with 2 or more non floating elements at its tail?

Answer (score 2):

(The third time today :-) ) give the outer div overflow: hidden;
and width.

Comment: Really?  So sorry about that, truly.  I think I have to work on changing my search queries to better express what other people call the same problem.

Comment: Adding a width to an element in order to make sure it grows in height makes CSS code hard to read, I doubt if that is a sensible solution. The zoom:1 solution seems better I guess but it will probably not be valid w3c css. The overflow: hidden also a nice solution but makes your css also hard to read because it is not about the overflow to hide content but used also to let the element grow in size.

Answer (score 1):

While the solutions above should work, I figure it's worth pointing out that there's one magical trick I haven't seen considered yet (in this thread).

Just float #div1 left. When you float the parent element, it'll automagically clear the child element - fairly useful, really. You could build an entire layout of floated stacks, and then have one final clear at the end, and it'd be fairly reliable.

Comment: Unfortunately floats are highly addictive.  Best to use them sparingly and sprinkle the odd overflow:hidden;