# Preceding divs are floated and collaps

Tags: html, css

I have floated divs, that are followed by a non-floated div. The following div ignores the height of the floated divs. What CSS comand is missing to prevent that?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kt3CH/)

html

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>    
    <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
```

css

```
.wrap{    
    width: 400px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.left{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    position : relative;
    float: left;
}


.right{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    position : relative;
    float: right;
}

.bottom{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    position : relative;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Float Creates Overlapping Divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023159/float-creates-overlapping-divs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add a clear to reset float like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="bottom">bottom</div>

</div>
```

usually is a good way to have a class named `clear` inside css to make this thing like:

```
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

and using it inside a div or a br like:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

or

```
<br class="clear" />
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kt3CH/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear floats.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <div class="bottom">bottom</div>        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clr{clear:both;}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kt3CH/3/)